# Spring MVC - Submit Form 400 Error

Tags: spring, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm just begin writing an application using Spring MVC. I have 2 entities, District & City. A City has many districts, and each district belongs to a city.

In district.jsp I declare a form, allowing user input of the district name and a selection box to choose the City it belongs to.

The District entity looks like this:

```
<form:form action="${aAction}" commandName="district">
<table>
    <c:if test="${!empty district.districtName}">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="id">
                <spring:message text="ID"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
            <form:hidden path="id" />
        </td> 
    </tr>
    </c:if>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="districtName">
                <spring:message text="District Name"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="districtName" />
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="belongToCity">
                <spring:message text="Belong to City"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <c:if test="${!empty listCities}">
                    <form:select path="belongToCity" items="${listCities}" itemLabel="cityName" itemValue="id"></form:select>
            </c:if>
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <c:if test="${!empty district.districtName}">
                <input type="submit"
                    value="<spring:message text="Edit District"/>" />
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${empty district.districtName}">
                <input type="submit"
                    value="<spring:message text="Add District"/>" />
            </c:if>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>    
</form:form>
```

In my district controller I declare add action.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/district/add"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addDistrict(@ModelAttribute("district") District p,Model model,  BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "district";
        }
        this.districtService.addDistrict(p);
        return "district";
    }
```

When I run my project, however, it shows a 400 error and the error message: "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."

I suspect my form is wrong somewhere, maybe it is not able to post to controller processing. Could someone help me identify the issue?

Comment: Whats value of ${aAction}

Answer (score 1):

Your BindingResult parameter should be adjacent to modelAttribute. Below should be method signature.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/district/add"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addDistrict(@ModelAttribute("district") District p,  BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "district";
        }
        this.districtService.addDistrict(p);
        return "district";
    }
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, was getting a 400 error when submitting a select input with no options selected. Reordered my method params and it works as expected! Up-voted your answer